# What's the deal with PrimitiveType in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

[I just noticed](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/05/01/persisting-enumeration-classes-with-nhibernate/) someone using the PrimitiveType class. It seems like an alternative to IUserType, but I can't find any documentation for it.
What is it for?

Comment: What context is it intended to be used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PrimitiveType` is a base class of primitive type implementations in NHibernate. It is not a `IUserType`, it is an IType. To me it seems not to be intended to be inherited outside of NHibernate, at least not for regular stuff. On the other side, it seems to be more powerful and it is also a public class. However, if you can solve your problem with a regular `IUserType`, I would recommend to use that.

All types in NH implement `IType`. The `PrimitiveType` is on the same level as the `CustomType`, which wraps an `IUserType`. So the `IUserType` is not an `IType` directly.

[image]